# Reflux store and actions flow logic: how to pass data from a store to another store

Tags: refluxjs

Is it Ok for a store to create an action to another store?

My data in `store A` always changing frequently, and i want to pass the data in `store A` to `store B` every time that my data in `store A` gets an update.

So I've made a listener in `store A`, on data change that's calling an handle function which "fire" an Action `dataChange(this.data)` (in `store A`) with the current data and store B gets the new data by `onDataChange(data)` every time the my data changed in `store A`.

So it's working, but i want to know if this is how i supposed to work with the data flow or there is more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Reflux philosophy, stores listening to other stores is an acceptable and supported pattern, just use the [listenTo method](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs#listening-to-changes-in-other-data-stores-aggregate-data-stores) in `store B` and listen to `store A`.